# Oldstyle (arabic) numbers in headings remove roman pagination

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, oldstylenums

Using the following code to get oldstyle (arabic) numbers in the headings make the preamble page numbers (in roman) to disappear. Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LE]{\oldstylenums{\thepage}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\oldstylenums{\thepage}}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\lipsum
\mainmatter
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

As you can see, in the frontmatter, there is no pagination on the headings (although there's still pagination at the bottom). Thanks.

Comment: You need to provide a minimal example. Something very simple like [this](http://pastebin.tlhiv.org/8sTuOGTy) works for me.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to... But in your example, \oldstylenums is ignored, since computer modern do not support them... Only computer latin. Could it be the reason?

Comment: There... I added one :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\makeatletter
\fancyhead[LE]{\if@mainmatter\oldstylenums{\arabic{page}}\else\thepage\fi}
\fancyhead[RO]{\if@mainmatter\oldstylenums{\arabic{page}}\else\thepage\fi}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 3):

\thepage gives a roman number in the frontmatter. \oldstylenums doesn't know what to do with it. If you want a number in the header use \fancyhead[LE]{\oldstylenums{\arabic{page}}}.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to ignore \oldstylenums if it is a roman numeral?

Answer (score 0):

```
\def\isnum#1{%
  \if!\ifnum9<1#1!\else_\fi
    \oldstylenums{#1}\else#1\fi}

\fancyhead[LE]{\isnum{\thepage}}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\isnum{\thepage}}}
```

Comment: `\thepage` can also be something like `my nice page 12`